# Why is my solution on LeetCode not working (recursion, python)?

Tags: python, recursion

```
class Solution:

    def climbStairs(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if n == 1:
            return 1
        if n == 2:
            return 2
        else:
            return self.climbStairs(n - 1) + self.climbStairs(n - 2)
```

My solution however is not working on Leetcode. Do you know why this is? Thank you so much!

I am trying to solve fibonacci sequence

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you Chris, is is fibonacci sequence

Comment: You probably need to check if n is less than one.

Comment: Do you have to solve via recursion? Fibonacci has a closed form solution based on the golden ratio. Your recursive solutions is `O(2**n)` which is very inefficient. Also, by default, python has quite a shallow recursion limit.

Comment: Is it not working or time limit error?

Comment: @  bigbounty, it says "time limit exceeded" However, in my personal compiler, their is no problem. Thank you

Comment: The answer to this question on stackoverflow is that you are getting a stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've chosen a poor algorithm.  It's not that it's recursive, just horribly inefficient.  Here's a more efficient recursive approach:

```
def climbStairs(self, n, res=1, nxt=1):
    if n == 0:
        return res
    return self.climbStairs(n - 1, nxt, res + nxt)
```

This runs much faster than your code and can go a lot higher before getting a stack overflow.  But it will eventually get a stack overflow.  We might do better adding memoization but ultimately, a simple iterative solution would be easier:

```
def climbStairs(self, n):  # doesn't use 'self', could be class method
    if 0 <= n <= 1:
        return 1

    a = b = 1

    for _ in range(n - 1):
        a, b = b, a + b

    return b
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks good but it's inefficient. You don't have to address if n==2 part. Keep it simple, like this:

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        if n == 0 or n == 1:
            return 1
        
        return self.climbStairs(n-1) + self.climbStairs(n-2)
```